# prometheus custom collector with "cached" metrics

Tags: python, prometheus

i want to have a prometheus collector that can be queried via http on port 9100 which is delivering a metric. the curl should always just provide the latest metric i am creating with my function here:

https://github.com/unnuetz/custom-prometheus-collector/blob/master/check.py#L5-L11

my problem now is, that after each cycle of 100secondes i added here:
https://github.com/unnuetz/custom-prometheus-collector/blob/master/main.py#L20-L23
the next metric i am creating is added, but i would like to have a "reset" after each call of checker(), and not that the individual metrics i created are always just added to my lets say registry.
is there a way, to remove all metrics which were added before?
the important thing ist, that between the 100seconds the start_http_server(9100, addr='0.0.0.0') is still availabe and delivering the latest metric data it have from the last checker() run.
in my demo file i always want to have just one metric with an random generated label name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using using builtin [Gauge](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#gauge), you can use a [custom collector](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#custom-collectors).

Note that it won't save you in Prometheus:

1. it will create a new metrics each time prometheus scrapes your application
2. the previous metric(s) will still be visible in Prometheus until it is marked as stale (~5 min).

If using using a custom collector is not an option because you need to show some code using *global* metrics. You can inject a `reset()` function similar to the [remove()](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/18d937159e4e90a1e212976859e2dc53f99980eb/prometheus_client/registry.py#L36) function using a bound method.

```
import CollectorRegistry from prometheus_client.registry

def _resetCollector(self):
    with self._lock:
        # reset whatever name / value you want
        pass

CollectorRegistry.reset = _resetCollector


# wherever you want to reset it
import REGISTRY from prometheus_client.registry
REGISTRY.reset()
```

Of course, it will break whenever the implementation of CollectorRegistry change.